# Render Razor View to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to render  my razor view to string. I would like to pass my model:

```
public class ContactDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and use it in my razor view and then render  it to the string.

I heard about RazorEngine but I would like to do it without it. **Also I don't have an controller context.**

Maybe I need fake some controller context?

Is it possible to do it? Do you have any idea how can to solve this problem?

Comment: Why must do that?

Comment: It is not duplicate because I don't want to use controller context

Comment: I think you mean 'render' not 'parse'. Why do you want to avoid `RazorEngine`? It's a lot of code to rewrite and this isn't the place to ask for a rewrite of it from scratch! As an alternative, you can do an HTTP request back to your own site and render the page that way.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if you're doing something that is going to make your life harder for no reason.

Comment: That's right I ment render.  So do you have any resources where I can find some tips how to do it?  I would like to write by myself without RazorEngine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render a view as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/483091/11683), but you must have a controller context. How can you run anything in ASP.NET MVC without one?

Comment: @GSberg I would like to use it in my service class, so how can I prepare my controller context ?

Comment: Your call begins in a controller where you have controller context. Pass it to where you need to render the view as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.RazorHosting - it shows how to render strings using the razor engine without a controller

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler library called [`Razor.Templating.Core`](https://github.com/soundaranbu/RazorTemplating) which works in both MVC and out of MVC Context. Supports .NET Core 3.1 and above versions.